# Delphi Parallel.For creating objects

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm trying to create a list of frames using parallelism to improve speed (with `Parallel.For()`).

The problem is that my code just don't run after this statement:

`lFrameItem := TFrameItemEntrega.Create(nil);`

Would I be expecting a lot of ease from Delphi with this function? I suspect this, because from what I've worked with threads, it's not that smooth.

What kind of function do I need to use to make this work?

I added debug messages to check where the code was stopping.

My `TFrameItemEntrega` doesn't have a personalized Creator, it's the standard `TCustomFrame` Creator.

Delphi Rio 10.3

```
procedure TfrmControleItensEntrega.CarregarFramesItensNota;
var
  lFrame: TFrameItemEntrega;
  lVenda: TVenda;
  Sync: TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer;
begin
  if TVenda.ExisteVenda(FNota) then
  begin
    lVenda := TVenda.Create;
    try
      lVenda.Nota := FNota;
      lVenda.CarregarItens := True;
      lVenda.CarregaVenda;

      FListaFramesItemLocal := TObjectList<TFrameItemEntrega>.Create;

      Sync := TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer.Create;
      try
        TParallel.for (0, Pred(lVenda.ListaDeItens.Count),
          procedure(I: Integer)
          var
            lFrameItem: TFrameItemEntrega;
          begin
            try
              OutputDebugString(pchar('enter'));
              lFrameItem := TFrameItemEntrega.Create(nil);
              OutputDebugString(pchar('exit'));
              lFrameItem.AtualizarFrame(lVenda.ListaDeItens[I].Produto.Codigo, lVenda.Cliente.Codigo,
                lVenda.ListaDeItens[I].Quantidade);
            except
              on E: Exception do
              begin
                OutputDebugString(pchar(e.Message));
              end;
            end;

            Sync.BeginWrite;
            try
              FListaFramesItemLocal.Add(lFrameItem);
            finally
              Sync.EndWrite;
            end;
          end);
      finally
        Sync.Free;
      end;

      if FListaFramesItemLocal.Count > 0 then
      begin
        for lFrame in FListaFramesItemLocal do
        begin
          lFrame.Align := alBottom;
          lFrame.Parent := sbxItens;
          lFrame.Align := alTop;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      lVenda.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: `TParallel.For()` runs its loop iterations in worker threads, but you can't create UI objects outside of the main UI thread, so the worker threads would have to sync with the main UI thread, which will kind of defeat the purpose of using threads to begin with. Why do you think creating the frames in parallel would increase your code's speed? Running more threads does not necessarily equate to faster processing. That is a myth that gets beginners to multi-threading in trouble.

Comment: First, you cannot construct UI objects in the background thread - they are not thread-safe. Second, even if you could, doing that wouldn't be faster because streaming form and frame from their resource file is also protected by global lock behind the scenes and this will definitely prevent from constructing them in the parallel. There is nothing to fix here as your approach is completely misguided. Forget about constructing frames background thread(s) of any kind.